# axios - send form data AND non-form data

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm using axios to send data to my nodejs/express server. If I want to send form data, I do the following (and it works fine):

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('nameOfFile', the_file);

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/someRoute',
    data: formData
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
}).then(response => {
   // Do something with response
}).catch(err => {
   // Do something with err
});
```

Again, the above code works fine. Here is the */someRoute* endpoint that it goes to:

```
app.post('/someRoute', (req, res) => {
    const uploadedFile = req.files.nameOfFile;
    res.send('success'):
});
```

The endpoint always successfully receives the file. So far, so good.

If I want to send some other piece of data, like a **date**, I can send it like so (and it also works):

```
const date = '2012-02-13';

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/someRoute',
    data: date
})

app.post('/someRoute', (req, res) => {
    const date = req.body.date;
    res.send('success'):
});
```

But how do I send **both** the **formDate** and **date** data? I tried the following (but it doesn't work):

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('nameOfFile', the_file);

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/someRoute',
    data: {
        form: formData,
        date: '2012-02-13'
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}).then(response => {
   // Do something with response
}).catch(err => {
   // Do something with err
});
```

And the endpoint:

```
app.post('/someRoute', (req, res) => {
    const uploadedFile = req.files.nameOfFile;
    const date = req.body.date;
    res.send('success'):
});
```

This gives me a **500 ERROR**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same thing you already did, just append the other data you also want to send to formData..
So 
          formData.append(‘date’, date);

Comment: I need to send a object. What should I do ?